# Facebook API get results by keyword

Tags: facebook, api

Is there a way with the Facebook APIS to get all the posts and people talking about a specific thread?

For example, I want to get all the posts that are about Nike.

Whever it finds the keyword Nike, it will return the post ID, Author ID etc.. etc..
This is possible with the Twitter API.
But what about the Facebook ones?
Any direction?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

well, there is one solution that might help you:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=keyword&type=post
```

the type can also be "page", "group" and whatnot.

**Edit: Public Post Search is deprecated and does not work anymore. Check out the docs for all possibilities with the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search**

Comment: How can I authenticate to get access?

Comment: that is a completely different question that has been answered often enough, i guess. you should start there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/