# Facebook Graphic API 2.8: Get page posts by date/keywords?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I want to get a page's posts by facebook graphic api(2.8, without FQL),
I have page_id, so I write something like this on graphic api testing page:

```
{post-id}/feed?limit=100
```

I know facebook only allow we get 100 posts,
is there any other way to get maybe number 101~200 posts?
or setting a keywords `parameters` like

```
{post-id}/feed?limit=100&keywords=apple
```

or setting a date duration `parameter` like

```
{post-id}/feed?limit=100&date=20160101_20161231
```

I only use graphic api testing page, so if it don't have to write any other codes, it will be very nice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit your result with *until* and *since* like this

`me?fields=feed.since(2016-12-20).until(2016-12-25).limit(4)`

Comment: Thanks! it works! I guess I have to make the keywords searching of my own

Comment: It seems that Facebook removed that feature or limited it. Take a look [here ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438331/facebook-api-get-results-by-keyword)